# When Parsing JSON feed using jquery and innerHTML data is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, feed

I'm trying to parse json feed using jquery and innerhtml however for some reason it is not working. No erros are showing in the console and the feed is working. not sure why it is not working

```
<div id="canvasFrame">


<div id='wrp' class='wrapper'>
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png"></img>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var feed;

    $.getJSON("feedurlinhere", function(result){
        console.log(result);
        feed = result;

        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrp');


        wrapper.innerHTML += "<div id='feedleft'><div class='container'><div class='tmb' style='background-image: url("+ feed.items[0].image +")'></div><h2>"+ feed.items[0].title +"</h2></div></div>";

        wrapper.innerHTML += "<div id='feedright'><div class='container'><div class='tmb' style='background-image: url("+ feed.items[1].image +")'></div><h2>"+ feed.items[1].title +"</h2></div></div>";
    });







</script>
```

Comment: Can you give us a response from the server?

Comment: This is the response [HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified 1399ms]

Comment: I think your response probably should contains JSON and returns HTTP/200...  Is your server-side works correctly?

Comment: Yes it works correctly

Comment: Why not innerHTML at once than twice? And Why assign result to feed? Make no sense.

Comment: Doing 2 innerHTML to show 2 items in the feed only one on the left and one on the right

Comment: I think if you don't like `result` var name, you should rewrite function to `function(feed)` instead creating another variable. My humble opinion. :)

Answer (score 0):

With few changes in the JavaScript and a correct feed, this code works fine

- I added the width and height to the `.tmb` div
- Replaced `'` with `"` in the HTML text

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrp');

var feed = {
  items: [{
    image: 'https://www.google.lk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
    title: 'Google Logo'
  }]
}

wrapper.innerHTML += '<div id="feedleft"><div class="container"><div class="tmb" style="background-image: url(\'' + feed.items[0].image + '\')"></div><h2>' + feed.items[0].title + '</h2></div></div>';
```

```css
.tmb {
  width: 540px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasFrame">


  <div id='wrp' class='wrapper'>
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png"></img>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes Shanaka this works but I am parsing data from json feed can I use this code but with jquery get json?

Comment: Just make sure that JSON request returns correct result with an items array. i did this without a JSON request because there's no way to recreate that request here.